# Обернуть в тег найденное через регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение `/([A-H][b#]?[m]?[\(]?(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7 \#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim 7|m\|maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|s us|sus2|sus4){0,2}(\/[A-H])?(\))?)(?=\s|\.|\)|-|\/)/g` Нужно чтоб все найденное в пределах тега `<pre>` оборачивались в тег `<span>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте полный вопрос с содержимым.

Comment: С помощью этого выражения можно выделать аккорды из любой песни. Мне нужно чтоб каждый аккорд был обернут при помощи js в тег  `<span>`, чтоб я мог стилизовать аккорды. Чтоб не прописывать в ручную для каждой песни тег `<span>`

Comment: Добавьте пример текста в `pre`

Comment: Am  
Лодка скрипит возле причала  
G  
Лунная ночь - тревог начало.  
Em         F  
Мрачно стою в воду смотрю.
Am
Нет моего в ней отраженья,
G
Есть только горечь пораженья.
Em         F
Ну почему лезть в мою жизнь
Am G F E
Вздумалось ему...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var regex = /([A-H][b#]?[m]?[\(]?(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7 \#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim 7|m\|maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|s us|sus2|sus4){0,2}(\/[A-H])?(\))?)(?=\s|\.|\)|-|\/)/g;
var some = document.querySelector('.something');
var res = some.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span> $& </span>');
some.innerHTML = res;
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<pre class="something">
Am Лодка скрипит возле причала
G Лунная ночь - тревог начало.
Em F Мрачно стою в воду смотрю.
Am Нет моего в ней отраженья,
G Есть только горечь пораженья.
Em F Ну почему лезть в мою жизнь
Am G F E Вздумалось ему...
</pre>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!